# c# append after match only once selection

Tags: c#, regex

I want to append to a richtextbox. I can append, but after the word is found, it keeps on appending multiple times. What I want to do is find the keyword, select the text and then append to the richtextbox only once. Here is the code:

```
        var Reg = new Regex(@"(\<\?)");
        var Matches = Reg.Matches(text);
        if (Matches.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Match mOne in Reg.Matches(text))
            {
                this.richTextBox1.Select(mOne.Groups[1].Index + firstCharIndex, mOne.Groups[1].Length);
                this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Azure;
                this.richTextBox1.AppendText("?>");
            }
        }
```

How can I select my text and append only once after the selection has been made?

Comment: So put a break in your foreach loop.

Comment: When do you call that code?

Comment: How can I put a break?

Comment: iterate through your matches backwards. so the indexes of earlier matches are not _invalidated_ by inserting text

Comment: @user3109009 to put a break in a loop.... just write the keyword `break;`

Comment: Why are you declaring `var Matches = Reg.Matches(text);` and in your foreach you use `Reg.Matches(text);` again instead of `var Matches`?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var Reg = new Regex(@"(\<\?)");
 var Matches = Reg.Matches(text);
 if (Matches.Count > 0)
 {
     var mOne = Matches.OfType<Match>().First();
     this.richTextBox1.Select(mOne.Groups[1].Index + firstCharIndex, mOne.Groups[1].Length);
     this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Azure;
     this.richTextBox1.AppendText("?>");
 }
```

Comment: This has the potential to be null.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
break;
```

After you append.

Comment: It does, it says to break the `foreach` loop after appending. If the answer is good or bad, that is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why go for a complicated answer :

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\<\?)", "$1" + textToAppend);
```

"$1" stands for the first group of the regexp.
In a regexp a group is a pair of parenthesis

It will append the text directly after the match

If your input string is : `"<?php"`

result content would be : `"<??>php"`

Comment: Do you think you can explain more?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(text, @"(something)", "$1" + this.richTextBox1.AppendText("other"));` does not function

Comment: The replacement will not be done in the input string, it will be returned as the method's result